# Passing URL with query parameters as function parameter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a URL that looks like

`https://go.feeds4.com/merchants/?pid=1676&mid=4261`

How do I pass this as a function parameter. I am trying to pass the value but not able to get anything in the function.

Does the `&` in query paramter cause issues?

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:;"
   onclick=rendernewmodal(<?php echo '"'.htmlspecialchars_decode($merchant->affiliate_link).'"'; ?>);>
  <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

On View Page Source, I can see the following

```
<a href="javascript:;"
   onclick=rendernewmodal("https://go.feeds4.com/merchants/?pid=1676&mid=4261");>
```

JS

```
function rendernewmodal(url) {
  alert (url);
}
```

I don't see any alert showing value of the URL. Please help.

Comment: onclick function is not under `" "`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. When putting data into an HTML document, you have to *encode* it for HTML not decode it *from* HTML
2. Attribute values need quoting when they contain certain characters (like quotes)

Mashing strings together to make JavaScript literals is error prone and messy, so you should avoid doing that by hand too.

So:

```
<?php
    # Get the URL
    $url = $merchant->affiliate_link;

    # Put quotes around it and escape special characters for JS
    $url_as_js_string_literal = json_encode($url);

    # Put it in the rest of the JS
    $js_function_call = "rendernewmodal($url_as_js_string_literal);";

    # Escape special characters for HTML
    $html_safe_js = htmlspecialchars($js_function_call);
?>
onclick="<?php echo $html_safe_js; ?>)">
```

Comment: i was doing htmlspecialchars_encode in PHP because the url was displaying &amp; instead of &

Comment: @GauravMehta — It's supposed to display `&amp;` *in the source code*. The browser will decode it it when parsing the HTML.

Comment: You sir are a genius. Thanks for the help.